# Insert/Update SQL Server Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have to insert or update into a table depending on a record. I am using a stored procedure to do this. I am very new to SQL Server and stored procedures. I tried to follow various articles and managed to create a stored procedure using MERGE.  The table looks likes this,

```
bl   em  number  title email fl name opt

null 101 00659   ABC   null  01 John null

null 102 00660   DEF   null  02 Rosy null
```

And the procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspInsUpd]
    @bl         char(8),
    @em         char(35),
    @number     char(12),
    @title      varchar(64),
    @email      varchar(50),
    @fl         char(4),
    @name       char(32),
    @opt        char(16),

AS

MERGE [dbo].[employee] AS [Target]
USING (SELECT @bl, @em , @number, @title, @email, @fl, @name, @opt)
   AS [Source] ( [bl], [em], [number], [title], [email], [fl], [name], [opt])  
ON [Target].[em] = [Source].[em]

WHEN MATCHED THEN
     UPDATE SET [bl]      = [Source].[bl],
                [em]      = [Source].[em],
                [number]  = [Source].[number],
                [title]   = [Source].[title],
                [email]   = [Source].[email],
                [fl]      = [Source].[fl],
                [name]    = [Source].[name],
                [opt]     = [Source].[opt],

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
     INSERT ( [bl], [number], [email], [fl], [name], [opt], [em],[title])
     VALUES ( [Source].[bl], [Source].[number], [Source].[email], [Source].[fl], [Source].[name], [Source].[opt], [Source].[em], [Source].[title]);
GO
```

Now I am not sure how can I test this stored procedure. Can anybody tell me if my above code is right?

Comment: [Please MERGE with caution](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/) - for updating or inserting a single row, why not `UPDATE ... IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 INSERT`?

Comment: Here it is going to be a set of records from a table.

Comment: How is that possible? Your procedure accepts exactly one value for each parameter and these map 1:1 with the columns in the table. Anyway, even if it's multiple rows and you pass via TVP or similar, then you can still do `UPDATE` with a `JOIN`, and `INSERT ... WHERE NOT EXISTS`.

Answer (score 2):

As a very generic answer, if you want to test code of this nature without actually changing the data then it is possible to run your code, query the results, and then undo any changes before they are committed.

```
-- Begin a new transaction
begin transaction

    -- Show initial data
    select * from [dbo].[employee]


    -- Your statement to change the data
    MERGE [dbo].[employee] AS [Target]
    ....
    ....
    ....


    -- Show the new data
    select * from [dbo].[employee]


-- Rollback the transaction, leaving the data in its original state.
rollback transaction
```